# Webdriver is not able to close the Browser

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm using IE. When I use the command driver.quit() or driver.close() to close the browser, an alert box pops up saying "do you want to navigate away from the webpage?" So How to accept the alert box when I've done quitting the WebDriver.

I'm getting session doesn't exist exception when trying to accept the alert.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the window **onbeforeunload** handler as null using java script before calling driver.quit() or driver.close()

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to the alert and then accept. This is how it looks like in ruby code.

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept
```

Java:

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```